# Use Nokogiri to select all <span> tags between a random selection of <br> tags

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse through some HTML using Nokogiri and Ruby and I'm coming at a bit of a snag doing exactly what I'd like to happen.  My sample file looks something like this:

```
<div id="main-body">
  <p>
    <span>First Text</span>
    <span>Second Text</span>
    <span>Third Text</span>
    <span>Fourth Text</span>
    <br>
    <span>Fifth Text</span>
    <span>Sixth Text</span>
    <span>Seventh Text</span>
    <br>
    <span>Eight Text</span>
    <span>Ninth Text</span>
    <br>
  </p>
</div
```

I'm trying to find a way to go through and select only text between random break tags or before the first break.

Basically I want to have my output be different each time I go through.  So example output would be eg

```
=>First Text
=>Second Text
=>Third Text
=>Fourth Text
```

one time, then, perhaps the next time it would get the stuff in between break 2 and 3

```
=>Eight Text
=>Ninth Text
```

I'm thinking that if I can count the number of breaks in the HTML I can then select a random one using rand() and print out text until I hit the next one, but I can't quite get it down correctly.

My code so far has been to load up the entire page into a Nokogiri type and try to parse from there.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(targeturl))
puts doc.xpath("./br").length #gives me the count of break tags in the document
```

From there I can actually assign the breaks to a variable and access them one by one but I'm not sure where to go or if I'm even on the right track from here and I feel like I'm just confusing myself at this point :/

Answer (score 1):

You could grab nodes based on the the preceding number of br tags by using `count()` and `preceding-sibling`.

```
puts doc.xpath("//span[count(preceding-sibling::br)=0]")
#=> <span>First Text</span>
#=> <span>Second Text</span>
#=> <span>Third Text</span>
#=> <span>Fourth Text</span>

puts doc.xpath("//span[count(preceding-sibling::br)=1]")
#=> <span>Fifth Text</span>
#=> <span>Sixth Text</span>
#=> <span>Seventh Text</span>

puts doc.xpath("//span[count(preceding-sibling::br)=2]")
#=> <span>Eight Text</span>
#=> <span>Ninth Text</span>
```

To get a random selection, just randomize the number of preceding-siblings:

```
puts doc.xpath("//span[count(preceding-sibling::br)=#{rand(doc.xpath("//br").length)}]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is slice_before:

```
doc.search('p *').slice_before{|x| x.name == 'br'}.each do |slice|
  puts '*', slice.select{|x| x.name == 'span'}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, if you only want the content of the span elements (to obtain the whole nodes, just remove the map operation):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("test.xml"))

def get_spans(doc)
    br_list = doc.css("br")
    br = br_list[rand(br_list.size)]

    span_list = []
    span = br.previous_element

    while span && span.name == "span"
         span_list << span
         span = span.previous_element
    end

    span_list.reverse.map(&:content)
end

p get_spans(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a single XPath one-liner expression that selects all the text nodes before the `$k`-th `br` but not before the `$k`-1th `br`:**

```
/*/p/br[2]/preceding-sibling::*[count(preceding-sibling::br)=1]/text()
```

So, if you have a random `k` in the interval `[1, count(/*/p/br)]`, then you simply substitute it in the above Xpath expression and evaluate it.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output  method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/p/br[2]/preceding-sibling::*[count(preceding-sibling::br)=1]/text()
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div id="main-body">
    <p>
        <span>First Text</span>
        <span>Second Text</span>
        <span>Third Text</span>
        <span>Fourth Text</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Fifth Text</span>
        <span>Sixth Text</span>
        <span>Seventh Text</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Eight Text</span>
        <span>Ninth Text</span>
        <br/>
    </p>
</div>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result from this evaluation (all selected text nodes) is copied to the output**:

```
Fifth TextSixth TextSeventh Text
```